# Location ID of cities changing in results from Geocoding Autocomplete API

Tags: here-api

I have noticed that Location IDs coming from the Geocoding Autocomplete API have been changing recently. I rely on location id to identify cities uniquely, so such changes cause us a lot of problems.

For instance city `Lodz, Poland` has currently location id `NT_wTVzyarLKGygLvsTPZ4VYD` while it used to be `NT_ROlJ6fdWSgsrVm8xPoZ1qD`.

As I understand (based on [Mismatch of location id between Geocoding Autocomplete and Geocoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591954/mismatch-of-location-id-between-geocoding-autocomplete-and-geocoding)), location ID value is based on the attributes identifying the value. In my scenario, I am searching for cities, so there was no change in the hierarchy of data, base names, etc. It is still the same city, in the same country and geographical area.

Shall I expect more changes of location ids for cities? Was the change intentional and what caused it?

Comment: We understood the issue but we need some more information regarding the query.

Could you please help us with the below information so that it will make it easier to dig it further.

1.Exactly what service are you using i.e. the URL , the query parameter and the version.
2.When did you find that there is a discrepancy in location ID in the response.
Regards, HERE Support